# Can't mount USB drive

Tags: raspbian, usb, mount, pi-1

My USB drive won't mount! When I try to mount it using this command:

`sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda /media/BackupUSB -o rw,umask=0000`

it would just say that it is already mounted or in use, but it doesn't appear in the eject menu. I restarted my Pi and now it says "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error."

I am running Raspbian Stretch, latest version. I am on a Pi B rev. 2.

Edit: I reformatted it and it still says it is busy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it.

I just had to add a `1` in `/dev/sda` to make it read `/dev/sda1`.